# What is the best way to delete image in MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

I created a MVC application where you can upload images. I'm storing them in file system and if file exist I'm showing it and Im not using SQL to track files.

I have a IList string with foreach showing them. but now I need to delete specific image and I'm not sure how to implement it in MVC because I can identify image just by imagename.

Could someone show me the best way of managing photos in my scenario. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 4):

You asked for an example, so here we go.
Let's imagine you would like to delete the picture stored in "/pics/path/mypic.jpg".
First you have to call

```
string path = Server.MapPath("/pics/path/mypic.jpg");
```

to get the physical path of the picture and store it in path variable.
Then you can do :

```
FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(path);
if(fi.Exists)
    fi.Delete();
else
    what you want to do if file does'nt exists.
```

Note : fi.Delete() doesn't throw exception if file doesn't exists.

To get the list of all files in a directory you can use Directory.GetFiles() or a DirectoryInfo instance.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to take a look at System.Web.HttpServerUtility.MapPath.  You can give it the virtual path of the image, (/images/picture.jpg) and it will give you back the absolute path (C:\web\mysite\images\picture.jpg).  Now you can delete the image.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure to understand the problem, MVC or something else : that's not important. Image is a file on the server, thus you can delete it like any other file, e.g using Server.Mappath to resolve FileInfo and play Delete on it.

Comment: Just need an example how to implement it. I cannot figure out how to accomplish it ...

Answer (score 0):

Now quite sure how to interpret your question... MVC seems quite out of context.

But... As I see it, you have a controller named ImageController with an Action called Delete. The action accepts a FormCollection parameter that when called, contains the name of the image.

So when when you delete you have a form which perform a POST to the ImageController->Delete Action and passes the name of the image with it. The name of the image is contained in a Hidden-field.

As a side-note: Using the name as identity might not be such a good idea. One reason is Directory Traversal Attacks. Ex providing ".../../../" instead of the image name. If you aren't good with white listing/validation of the data inputed, this kind of attack will likely be possible.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directory_traversal